# Reccurence in outlook using EWS trying to go over 09/01/4500

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use EWS to create appointments for someone else with required permissions.
I've managed to make all the properties to work so far. However, the reccurence is giving me a headache.

```
Dim Pattern As New WeeklyRecurrencePatternType
Pattern.Interval = 1
Pattern.DaysOfWeek = Now.DayOfWeek.ToString
Rec.Item = Pattern
```

THAT shouldn't pose any more of a problem than, say,

```
Dim Pattern As New DailyRecurrencePatternType
Pattern.Interval = 1
Rec.Item = Pattern
```

Daily, monthly, yearly work. Weekly doesn't. It throws the exception:
"La date de fin de la périodicité ne peut pas excéder le 1er sept 4500 00:00:00."
which in english translates as 
"The end date of the reccurence may not exceed sept 1st 4500 00:00:00."

Trying to find ANYTHING on google or bing doesnt yield any result(not even the correct translation).

I'm not using the API since the hardware/software dept. guys forbid us using it, so it's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are forgetting to tell Exchange about the duration of your recurrence pattern. Either specify `StartDate` and `NumberOfOccurrences`, or `StartDate` and `EndDate`,  or `StartDate` and `NoEndRecurrence`.

See [Recurrence patterns and EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn727655%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

I don't know how to do this in your language, because I only 'do' raw SOAP calls. If anyone knows the exact syntax to use, feel free to edit this answer and replace this paragraph.

I have no idea why Exchange only complains when making a weekly recurrence.